# Parsing local xml file data on basis of particular condition

Tags: android

How can I show `XML` tag values on basis of particular condition using local `XML` parsing.

E.g. I have this `XML` file stored in assets folder,

```
<language>
<languagename>English</languagename>
<contact>EContact</contact>
<update>EUpdate</update>
</language>

<language>
<languagename>Hebrew</languagename>
<contact>HContact</contact>
<update>HUpdate</update>
</language>
```

I have two buttons, when I click English I want to show data Regarding English and when    I click Hebrew , I want to show only Hebrew. Please provide help.

Thanks

Comment: Use a SaxParser to construct objects of a Language class and store them inside a Hashmap,where the language is the key and the other information is the value.

Comment: Thank you chaitanya, I am trying can you please provide me a sample example as I am  fresh to android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the XML parser Function it takes the XML as String.

```
public class XMLParser {
    public static void parser(String s) {
        try {
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
            MyXMLhandler h = new MyXMLhandler();
            xr.setContentHandler(h);
        //  Log.e("string", s);
            xr.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(s)));

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("ParserError", e.getMessage());
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("SAXError", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("IOError", e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Use this handler class to extract the information that u need:

```
public class MyXMLhandler extends DefaultHandler {
private boolean language = false;
private boolean languagename = false;
private boolean contact = false;
private boolean update = false;


@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("language")) {
        language = true;
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("languagename")) {
        languagename = true;
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("contact")) {
        contact = true;
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("update")) {
        update = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("language")) {
        language = false;
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("languagename")) {
        languagename = false;
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("contact")) {
        contact = false;
    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("update")) {
        update = false;
    }
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {

    if (language == true) {
        String s = new String(ch, start, length);

        Log.w("Language", s);

    }
    if (languagename == true) {
        String s = new String(ch, start, length);

        Log.w("Languagename", s);

    }
    if (contact == true) {
        String s = new String(ch, start, length);

        Log.w("contact", s);

    }
    if (update == true) {
        String s = new String(ch, start, length);

        Log.w("update", s);

    }

}
```

}

Use this function above and modify it to solve ur problem

Comment: Sory I cant as I dont have enough reputations. Thanks for your support.